# Exchange Powershell Loop Distribution List

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I have this Powershell-Script that `Gets-DistributionGroupMembers` and or Update the member's policy.

```sh
$DL = Get-DistributionGroupMember "Distribution List GroupName"
ForEach ($Member in $DL) { Set-CASMailbox -Identity $Member.Name -OwaMailboxPolicy "Allow Download Access" }
```

The above code is working okay.

My question is:

1. how do you check if `$Member.Name` is an individual account or a group
2. and *IF*  its a group, Then how do you call the same **Action Script** recursively.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but I think you can determine if the member is a group or not by checking the [RecipientTypeDetails](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/exchange-server-api/ff344739(v%3Dexchg.150)) property.

Something like:

```
function Set-DistributionGroupPolicy([string] $group) {
    Get-DistributionGroupMember $group -ResultSize Unlimited | ForEach-Object {
        if ($_.RecipientTypeDetails -match "Group") {
            Write-Verbose "Recursing on group '$($_.Name)'"      
            Set-DistributionGroupPolicy $_.Name
        }
        Set-CASMailbox -Identity $_.Name -OwaMailboxPolicy "Allow Download Access"
    }
}

Set-DistributionGroupPolicy
```

Comment: the `RecipientTypeDetails`  is very handy. thank you!